# Firebase User ID and Current User ID on code do not match

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase and I assumed the user id generated by Firebase Database is the same one I get by using `currentUser.getUid()`. But as you can see, those two values don't match for my current user.

I can't figure out the reason. Please help. How to solve this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see in your screenshots you are using two different ways for having that unique key, a `uid` provided by the `firebaseUser` object and the unique key generated by the `push()` method. It's obvious that are not the same, becase there are different principles.

The first one is the `uid` provided by the Firebase authentication and the second by the `push()` method, that generates a unique id based on the time of the generation.

The best way for using as an identifier for your users is not the `uid`, nor the `pushed id`, is the email address, because if a users deletes his account and sign-in again, he'll gets a new `uid`.

If you want to use the `uid`, this is the way in which you can retrieve it:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please tell me the right way to retrieve the firebase user id? Or provide me a link for it?

Answer (score 1):

Those are totally different things.
 ID that you get with `getUid()` is an ID that is created when user is signed up to Firebase Authentication. Other one is key created based on the current timestamp in the Firebase Database when you call `push()` method.
 What you could do is instead of creating new person in your database with push method, use the id that you get from `getUid()`